# How to make one column mirror another in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one called users and another called profiles. Each of these tables has a column named user_id. What I want to do is when I insert a new user into the users table, I want to automatically copy over their new user_id in the users table to the profiles table. I don't want to use the UPDATE clause because then I would have to call that every time I add a new user. I thought that relations would achieve what I am trying to do so I made the user_id from profiles reference the user_id from users and it still doesn't update automatically. What should I do? And what is the point of relations in the first place if they don't update your columns automatically?

Comment: you would make a trigger in this case to INSERT the other corresponding row.

Comment: You can use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the `users` table to insert into the `profiles` table automatically.

Comment: Relations between tables are not usually one-to-one, so automatic updates would not be appropriate. Also, how would it know what to put into the other columns if it inserted automatically?

Comment: Also, it's normal behavior to NOT have an entry in profiles just because the user exists -- that just means that they haven't created a profile yet.  You can control whether you see this via your joins -- if you `select * from users u left join profiles p on u.user_id=p.user_id` then you'll get rows for every user with `null` in the profile columns for users with no profile.  If you do an `inner join` instead, then your results will completely leave out users with no profile.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a design error. If rows in these two tables always exist with the same IDs, they should probably be a single table.

The foreign key you've created only guarantees that every row *that exists* in `profiles` must have the same ID as a row in `users`. It does not cause those rows to be created -- it just means that if you try to create a row with an ID that doesn't match, the database will throw an error.

That all being said, it's possible to create a trigger to do what you're describing:

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_insert_creates_profile
    AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO profile (user_id) VALUES (NEW.user_id);
```

But it's probably better to reconsider your design, or to do the insert in your application. Triggers are best avoided.

Comment: Alright thanks! I was originally going to make it a single table but then there would be so many columns which would make it difficult to read in cmd. I suppose that's not to big of an issue though.

Comment: I have to add to this that I have a technical consideration as to why I needed this: I wanted to store the same data in two different storage engines in MySQL for the purpose of fetching the data in different (accelerated) ways. InnoDB for the transactional security, and another table as a simple "search" table using a different storage engine that optimizes the searches I need better